# Tailwind CSS with Next.js not applicable

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Introduced Tailwind CSS to the Next.js environment.
I want to apply `color.lime`, but I get the following error.

```
./node_modules/tailwindcss/tailwind.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-5-2!./node_modules/tailwindcss/tailwind.css)
ReferenceError: color is not defined
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
const colors = require(`tailwindcss/colors`);
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  darkMode: false, // 'media' or 'class'
  theme: { extend: { colors: { lime: color.lime } } },
  variants: { extend: {} },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**__app.tsx**

```
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import Head from "next/head";

const App = (props: AppProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>nexst</title>
      </Head>
      <props.Component {...props.pageProps} />
    </>
  );
};

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-default-export
export default App;
```

Comment: Have you tried moving `colors: { lime: color.lime }` outside of `extend: { }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your `tailwind.config.js`, you should access the color with `colors.lime` rather than `color.lime`.

```
const colors = require(`tailwindcss/colors`);
module.exports = {
    purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
    darkMode: false, // 'media' or 'class'
    theme: { extend: { colors: { lime: colors.lime } } }, // here use `colors`
    variants: { extend: {} },
    plugins: [],
};
```